# Unable to grab the value of data generated from PHP-MYSQL using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The title doesn't say much about the question. Here is what I am trying to achieve. I sent AJAX request using jQuery from HTML form to a php file that successfully sends back required data to AJAX. I am also able to see this values. Here is my problem: When I try to get value of a single element using their attribute, I am not able to get it. This will be more clear when you see my jQuery code

```
var temp_client_name;
$("#temp_client_name").on('click', 'li', function(){
    temp_client_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //temp_client_name = $("#"+temp_client_id).html();
    temp_client_name = $("li[id='+temp_client_id+']").html();
    $("#client_name").val(temp_client_name);
    console.log('temp_client_name ' + temp_client_name);
});
```

Now, the problem is in line 5 (alternative to line 4 which works same way I suppose and so I commented out that line as it is a good alternative to achieve same thing).
In line 3, I get the ID of the HTML element whose value I am interested in and it is an attribute of li tag. And this is also working fine, I am getting the ID of required element. So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line

```
temp_client_name = $("li[id='+temp_client_id+']").val();
```

means get val of `li` wich id is `+temp_client_id+`.
If you want to use `temp_client_id` variable:

```
temp_client_name = $("li[id='" + temp_client_id + "']").val();
```

But I don't understand why do you do this, cause accessing element by `id` can be done just like

```
value = $( "#id" ).val();
```

Comment: Thank you! But why is this line not working? temp_client_name = $("#"+temp_client_id).val();

Comment: What does `console.log(temp_client_name)` shows when you try `temp_client_name = $("#"+temp_client_id).val();`? Are ids on your page unique?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"` before and after `+` in :

```
temp_client_name = $("li[id='"+temp_client_id+"']").val();
```

But why not use :

```
temp_client_name = $(this).val();
```

Instead of :

```
temp_client_id = $(this).attr('id');
//temp_client_name = $("#"+temp_client_id).val();
temp_client_name = $("li[id='"+temp_client_id+"']").val();
```

Comment: That worked fine. I cannot up vote this answer as I dont have privileges. Can you also suggest why temp_client_name = $("#"+temp_client_id).val(); is not working?

Answer (score 0):

you have got some mistakes in your code.

1. The id of the elements must be unique
2. html tag `<li></li>` doesn't contain value attribute (so val() is not usefull here)
3. this line `temp_client_name = $("li[id='+temp_client_id+']").val();` is not working at all because you have got wrong concatenation; its must look like this `$('li[id='+your_variable_here+']').val();`
4. Check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/52hrLdkg/

   `var temp_client_name;
   $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    temp_client_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    temp_client_name = $('#'+temp_client_id).val();
    alert('temp_client_name ' + temp_client_name);
   });`

Comment: That was my bad! Sorry,I switched it to .html()